# Geometric Proof of Wilson's Theorem

Tags: geometry, number-theory

I have read an article about geometric proof of Wilson's theorem, the link is here
[Proof](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/GeometricWilson.shtml#:%7E:text=It%20follows%20that%20the%20total,like%20say%2C%2013245...&text=The%20latter%20number%20is%20divisible,by%20p%2C%20proving%20Wilson%27s%20theorem.)

The article said that when drawing star shape, skipping k vertices is the same as skipping $p - k + 2$ of them. Like the comment mentioned, it does not seems correct, so  I have come up another equation which is skipping k vertices is the same as skipping $p-k-2$ when $k \leq p-1$. I have tried this by taking $p=5$, $7$ and $13$, and it seems legit. However, I don't know how to prove it.

I would appreciate if anyone could explain this part.

Comment: "skipping $k$ vertices is the same as skipping $p-k+2$" are you sure? Take $p=5$ and $k=2$. If you skip 5 vertices you're drawing the 5-gon, not the pentagram.

Comment: @AlvinLepik This is the part I don't agree with the article, so I come up with a new equation. But i want to know what it is always true.

Comment: It probably intends to say "$p-k-2$".

Comment: @DRSKMOBINULHAQUE I think so, but if that is true, I am interested in knowing the proof.

Comment: This video may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qbh7mC6YCY&t=517s&ab_channel=Cheenta

Comment: @HTLL Every time we are skipping $k$ vertices, $p-k-2$ vertices are being left, the additional two vertices being the vertex where we started from and the vertex on which we land after skipping $k$ vertices.Thus when we skip $p-k-2$ vertices,  $k$ vertices are left.

Comment: @DRSKMOBINULHAQUE Thanks, it makes a lot of sense now

Comment: I think the easiest way to prove Wilson's Theorem is (1). If $p$ is prime then multiplication mod $p$ on $\{1,...,p-1\}$ is a finite commutative group. (2). If $R$ is the product of all the members of  a finite commutative group  $G$ with identity element $1$, then the members of $G$ that are not their own inverses will cancel out in pairs in the product $R$, so $R$ is the product of the members of $\{x\in G: x^2=1\}.$